# How to add a event handler to catch leaflet contextmenu events?

Tags: events, leaflet, contextmenu, handler

I create a context menu like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 15,
    gestureHandling: ControlGestual,
    contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuWidth: 300,
    contextmenuItems: MenuContextual
});
```

but I also need some code to be executed when the context menu is closed(hidden).  I see in the documentation that there is a contextmenu.hide event, but I don't know how to create a handler for this event.

I would appreciate your help. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is fired on the map, so add:

```
map.on('contextmenu.hide', (e)=>{
    console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: Many thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct, so it get the green mark